# A interesting max min problem

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, optimization

Let $\mathcal{S}\subset\mathbb{R}^2$ be a bounded, closed, compact, convex set which contains origin in its interior.

Define 
\begin{align}
c_1^{\star}=\min_{{(x_1,0)\in\mathcal{S}}}~&x_1
\end{align}
Also define
\begin{align}
\lambda(t)&=\min_{(x_1,x_2)\in\mathcal{S}}~~x_1+tx_2 \\
c_2^{\star}&=\max_{t}\lambda(t)
\end{align}
Then is it true that 
\begin{align}
\lambda(t) \leq c_1^{*}
\end{align}
irrespective of choice of $t$.

Also, when is the following true
\begin{align}
c_2^{\star}= c_1^{\star}
\end{align}

Comment: Is the $x_2=0$ supposed to be under the $\min$, so $c_1^*$ is the minimum of $x_1$ along the axis?

Comment: That is, do you mean 
$c_1^{\star}=\min_{{(x_1,0)\in\mathcal{S}}} x_1$ ? (And if not, what is $x_2=0$ supposed to convey on its own?)

Comment: In $R^2$, compact = closed + bounded (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bolzano%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem). You can remove some of those terms.

Comment: @RossMillikan yes, I corrected the question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is true that $\forall t \lambda (t) \le c_1^*$ because one candidate point for $\lambda(t)$ is $(x_1,0)$ at which point $x_1+tx_2=x_1$, so minimizing over $S$ must be less than or equal to this.  One candidate value for $c_2^*$ is $\lambda(0)=c_1^*$.  Since $c_2^*$ is the maximum over $t$, it can't be less than this.  If $S$ is an axis aligned rectangle that straddles the $x$ axis, $c_1^*$ will be the $x$ coordinate of the left edge.  For $t \gt 0$, $\lambda(t)$ will be obtained at the lower left corner and $\lambda(t) \lt \lambda(0)$.  For $t \lt 0$, $\lambda(t)$ will be obtained at the upper left corner and again less than $\lambda(0)$.  So $c_2^*=\lambda(0)=c_1^*$

Added:  Yes, it is true for all compact $S$ that include at least one point of the $x$ axis (not necessarily convex, nor necessarily including the origin in the interior) that $c_2^*=c_1^*$.  Because $S$ is compact, the intersection of $S$ and the $x$ axis is closed and there is a leftmost point in the intersection.  This point is $(c_1^*,0)$.  Let us define $L(x_1,x_2,t)=x_1+x_2t$ for $(x_1,x_2) \in S$.  Then $\lambda(t)=\min_{(x_1,x_2)\in S}L(x_1,x_2,t)$  Clearly $\forall t\lambda(t) \le L(c_1^*,0,t)=c_1^*$, so $c_2^* \le c_1^*$.  We showed above that $c_2^* \ge c_1^*$, so $c_2^*=c_1^*$

Comment: Isn't $\lambda(t)$ the minimum over $(x_1,x_2)\in\mathcal{S}$ for a given $t$?

Comment: Yes, but the point is that there will be some $t$ that makes $\lambda (t) \gt c_1^*$, so $c_2^* \gt c_1^*$.    For $\lambda(t)$ you pick $t$ first, then minimize over the point.  For $c_2^*$ you pick $t$ first, find the point that minimizes it, and pick the highest.  The order of picking is critical.

Comment: So whether $c_2^{\star}\leq c_1^{\star}$ will depend on the nature $\mathcal{S}$, is that what you are saying?

Comment: The argument in the last comment you put forward is what confused me actually. For a given $t$, I have to select a $(x_1,x_2)\in\mathcal{S}$. When I go to a new $t$, won't this $x_2$ change? So how does this unboundedness happen. Also, note that $\lambda(t)$ is a concave function. If you assume there is a point which attains the maximum, then if you move away from $t$, shouldn't it decrease?

Comment: I have rewritten it completely.  See if this works.

Comment: so, you are saying that $c_1^{\star}\leq c_2^{\star}$ in general. For that particular choice of $\mathcal{S}$ you made, they are equal, Though, in general, it is not so.